# What is the difference in SR gained when playing solo vs a group?

Tags: overwatch

I was playing Overwatch a bunch this weekend and was trying to climb in competitive so I played with a couple friends as well. I noticed that there seems to be a big difference between the SR gained when playing solo vs playing with a group.

I was earning upwards of 30-35 SR per win alone, with 1 friend I was getting around 20-25, and with a group of 4-6 people I was only getting upwards of 15 SR per win.

I tried looking up to see if Blizzard had released any sort of formula for how it's determined, but wasn't able to find anything, maybe I missed something.

**So in short, is there a formula, or some way that SR is determined the more players you are grouped with?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand things from numerous different Blizzard statements:

There's a consecutive win bonus on SR. The more consecutive games you win, the more SR you get. Although I'm not sure about the following, it would appear that the consecutive bonus is different for different group sizes. That's why you weren't getting as much with a larger party than all by yourself.

Another point worth mentioning is how much SR you get has absolutely nothing to do with group size, how well you did, how well any of the group members did, etc. The game takes how well you performed and compares you to other players of the same hero in a similar MMR (Match Making Rank) to yours. This means if you're an above average player with a given hero, you'll get more SR if I played the same hero, and the game ended in exactly the same way.

Comment: If i remember correctly, win streaks have had their effects lessened or may be going away altogether.

Comment: Yeah win streak stuff is pretty much going away. Maybe it's based off what you said about being compared to MMR of others. When you're in a group and your SR average is what you play at, I guess it is raising the MMR as well? So then you are being compared to even better players which is why it's less SR?

Comment: I think it's because when you queue with friends, you know that they are on your skill level and able to play well. This therefore raises the bar and makes your averages lower compared to the rest of the team, so you gain less SR